# How to pass a complex url to a generic class Update view in django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to create an update view for my django blog project and I haven't been able to figure it out. I have a model that creates a url based on the date it was posted and the title which also goes through a random slug generator it was given and Im having trouble passing that url to the update view I keep getting the error "AttributeError at /posts2020/7/24/hello-93ej/update/
Generic detail view PostUpdateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf"

here is my code

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('cleared','Cleared'),('UnderReview','Being Reviewed'),('banned','Banned'),)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 300, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='forum_posts',null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='cleared')
    objects = models.Manager()
    cleared = PublishedManager()
    class Meta:
        ordering =('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .views import PostListView, PostCreateView,PostUpdateView
app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/',PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/update/',PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
```

views.py

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post-update', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

post-update.html

```
{% extends "Main/Base.html" %}
{% block title %} Update a post {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1> Update a post <h1>
    <p>You can Update your post using the following form:</p>
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Update"></p>
    </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the objects by overriding the `get_object`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body']

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_obect_or_404(
            Post,
            publish__year=self.kwargs['year'],
            publish__month=self.kwargs['month'],
            publish__day=self.kwargs['day'],
            slug=self.kwargs['post'],
            author=self.request.user
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'posts:post-update',
            args=[
                self.object.publish.year,
                self.object.publish.month,
                self.object.publish.day,
                self.object.slug
            ]
        )
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The `author=self.request.user` filter part, will ensure that if the logged in user is not the author, it will raise a HTTP 404 response instead of letting that user edit the post.

Comment: Aside from that, I don't think self.publish exists...

Comment: @Melvyn: well the object has a `publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)`

Comment: Yep, the self.object does, cause we're in the view here.

Comment: @Melvyn: yes, I realised that a few seconds after commenting ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help that worked as expected, I just need to check if the author is the person attempting to edit it now

Comment: @JoeG: you can filter on `author=request.user` as well. See edit.